# Dismiss info-window in android google map after click info-window?

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow, dismiss

Hi I want to dismiss android Google map info-window when I clicked info-window.Normally when I clicked map it dismiss.But I also need when user click the info-window then also dismiss info-window.

```
 @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    // dismiss info-window
       }
```

I want to know is there way to dismiss after i clicked info-window in android.
Thanks
Sajith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set the GoogleMap's Info Window Click Listener, best done in your 'onCreate'. Easiest to just make the Activity/Fragment implment GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener.

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
```

Then set up your listener method and just call 'marker.hideInfoWindow();'.

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    marker.hideInfoWindow();
}
```

That should do it.